# How build Vaadin project with gradle?

Tags: vaadin, gradle

I have gradle project (backend) and I want to add Vaadin-based frontend. But I haven't find any gradle-plugins for Vaadin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no a Vaadin plugin for Gradle but I have used Gradle in one of my Vaadin add-on projects: [SplitButton](https://github.com/henrikerola/SplitButton). It's a project with sub-projects, widgetset compilation and it writes necessary jar manifest entries neebed by Vaadin Directory.

**EDIT**
Actually there is Gradle Vaadin plugin now - it allows you to easily build Vaadin projects with Gradle. It helps with the most tedious tasks when building a Vaadin project like building the widgetset and running development mode. It also helps you to quickly get started by providing tasks for project, component and theme creation:

https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin

Answer (score 5):

While, as was already mentioned above, Vaadin app is a simple web application and does not require any additional plugins but "java" and "war" (and maybe "jetty" to run the app), currently there seems to be the first vaadin-specific gradle plugin available:

https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin

It will help you with Vaadin-specific task like building widgetsets, creating components skeletons, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a Vaadin plugin. A Vaadin application is simply a web application.The war plugin will suffice. If you want support for automatically creating the folder layout that Vaadin wants however, you might look into using the vaadin eclipse plugin found here:

http://vaadin.com/eclipse

If you are looking for deployment support, you can simply use the jetty plugin that comes with gradle or the tomcat plugin found here

https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin

If you need to create custom widgets and compile them into a widgetset that's a GWT compile

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/gwt.development.html#gwt.development.compiler

Note: The Vaadin7 Book no longer has the section on developing Gwt widgets.

There is a gradle plugin for GWT that could help with that. However, I've not needed a custom widget yet, so I haven't actually tried it.

https://github.com/markuskobler/gwt-gradle-plugin

Comment: You must create the Widget of Vaadin (GWT). It exist a plugin for Maven, but no one for Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

This [post](http://www.jasoft.fi/?entry=Using-Gradle-with-Vaadin):

### [Using Gradle with Vaadin](http://www.jasoft.fi/?entry=Using-Gradle-with-Vaadin)

looks very comprehensive as far as Gradle+Vaadin setup goes. I'm also including [a link to another Vaadin-based 'build.gradle'](http://code.google.com/p/isdinvestments/source/browse/trunk/gradle.properties) file I found on my travels, using [Google's very useful 'filetype' search](https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype%3Agradle%20vaadin) (see also the associated [gradle.properties](http://code.google.com/p/isdinvestments/source/browse/trunk/gradle.properties) file).

JFYI that Google file search is:

```
filetype:<extension> <your search phrases>
```

Gradle can also be used to configure Eclipse and IntelliJ's project files by using a fragment such as the following (Eclipse natures can be 'found' by using the above Google file search for "project" extension and "natures" search, etc.):

```
//Template plugin - Great for project-layout setup - See http://tellurianring.com/wiki/gradle/templates
apply from: 'http://launchpad.net/gradle-templates/trunk/latest/+download/apply.groovy'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

// if you want to distribute the gradle with your code
task('wrapper', type: Wrapper).configure {
    gradleVersion = '1.0-milestone-8a'
}

def versionCompatibility = 1.6

//configurations.providedDependencies.extendsFrom configurations.gwt

eclipse {
    project {
        comment = ""

        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.javascriptValidator"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder"
        buildCommand "com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.widgetsetBuilder"
        //buildCommand "org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder"
        //buildCommand "org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Builder"
        //buildCommand "com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator"
        //buildCommand "com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator"
        //buildCommand "com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.GWTBuilder"


            //Don't forget commas - no trailing
            natures "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature",
            "com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.widgetsetNature",
            "org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature",
            "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature",
            "org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature",
            "org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature"
            //"org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature",
            //"org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature",
            //"com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature"
            //"com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.GWTNature",
            //"ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.core.scalanature",
            //"com.springsource.sts.grails.core.nature",
            //"org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature"
    }

    classpath {
            containers "com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"
            //"com.springsource.sts.gradle.classpathcontainer"

            //minusConfigurations=[configurations.gwt]
    }
}

idea {
    project {
            jdkName = versionCompatibility

        ipr {
                withXml { provider ->
                    def node = provider.asNode()

                    // Set Gradle home
                    def gradleSettings = node.appendNode('component', [name: 'GradleSettings'])
                    gradleSettings.appendNode('option', [name: 'SDK_HOME', value: gradle.gradleHomeDir])
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Rich